# Max date oracle returning null

Tags: oracle, date, max

I have a query in a function which is returning a null date and I am a little unclear as to why.

the query is

```
    select max(as_of_date)
    from thresholds
    where as_of_date = (select max(as_of_date)
                        from thresholds
                        where as_of_date <= in_as_of_date));
```

The in_as_of_date is being pass into the function but is adding a year to the date being passed in.
Here is the call:

```
    l_Amount := fmwrk_utl.f_getAmount(inAsOfDate => ADD_MONTHS(l_effective_date,12));
```

So for this instance, l_effective_date of 01-JAN-98 will be 01-JAN-99

In the threshold table exists two records

```
AS_OF_DATE | AMOUNT

11-SEP-12  | 50
01_JAN-11  | 40
```

It seems that any data with an effective date greater than 1999 returns no as of date from the threshold table. I'm unclear as to why. Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Well, both 11-Sep-12 and 01-Jan-11 are after 01-Jan-99, assuming you're two-digit years are RR-based. If you're passing strings about and doing implicit date conversion, don't, but what is your NLS_DATE_FORMAT? Might also be worth checking the 4-digit years for the values in your table, as well as your passed value. Hard to tell but looks like century confusion.

Comment: The difference between 01-JAN-98 and 01-JAN-99 is one YEAR, not one MONTH. You might want to edit your question to correct this. Thanks.

Comment: what does `select in_as_of_date from dual` return?

Comment: @AlexPoole: years are RR based, I originally thought this was an issue with the date format. It turns out that the select was functioning correctly. The data it is querying against has records less than 2011. Apparently this shouldn't ever be the case. That would explain why I was getting the null dates.

Comment: @BobJarvis: yes, you are correct, guess I had months on the mind. ;)